# Error al obtener nombre de pc del cliente desde el servidor PHP

Tags: php, laravel

tengo mi sistema en un servidor, y lo que hace es obtener el nombre de la pc con php

primero agregue de esta forma: (Pero solo obtengo nombre del servidor)

```
gethostname();
```

Despues probe con este codigo y lo que obtuve es el ip del cliente pero no el nombre de la pc

```
gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

Hay alguna otra forma de obtener el nombre de la pc del cliente?

Comment: @BetaM puse tambien ese codigo, pero me devuelve mi ip mas no el nombre de la pc

Comment: @BetaM he actualizado con los codigos que use

Comment: Por razones de seguridad no puedes acceder a datos sensibles del cliente. Por ejemplo, puedes obtener la IP pública, pero nunca la IP que usa el equipo en la red interna.

Comment: @Triby entonces no hay forma de obtener el nombre de la pc de forma remota?

Comment: Es correcto, no hay forma de obtenerlo, a menos que el cliente descargue e instale un programa o extensión y, en todo caso, debería proporcionar permisos para acceso a datos.

Comment: No hay forma de hacer eso, es parte de la seguridad de internet. Si estás trabajando en una red local, podrías hacer una lista con todas las estaciones y hacer match con el IP. Por otro lado, desconozco si se pueda hacer un DNS lookup al DNS server de la red, posiblemente si.

Comment: @Triby conoces algun programa o extension que me pueda ayudar a capturar ese dato y poder enviarlo a mi sistema?

Answer (score -1):

Yo tambien he estado intentando hacer lo mismo, antes me funcionaba esto:

```html
<?php
//Obtiene la MAC de cada equipo
$MAC = exec('getmac');
$MAC = strtok($MAC, ' ');

//Obtiene la IP de cada equipo
$ip  = getenv("REMOTE_ADDR");

//Obtiene nombre del equipo
$ip  = getenv("COMPUTERNAME")." IP: ".$ip;

echo $ip;
?>
```

espero te sirva

Comment: Esto te mostrará solo la información del equipo donde se está ejecutando PHP, es decir del servidor y la pregunta dice "Hay alguna otra forma de obtener el nombre de la pc del cliente?".

Solo `REMOTE_ADDR` es información del cliente.